# How to play audio codec not natively supported by Android

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Part of the functionality of my app is to play videos that are taken by a trail camera. My problem is the audio codec of the videos the camera produces is not natively supported by Android, and therefore no sound is played during video playback.

The videos the cameras take are MP4 format, which from what I understand, is simply a wrapper for the video and audio codecs. I used VLC Media Player to play the videos to determine the audio codec to be sowt (AIFF-C).

[Here is a screenshot of the VLC Media Player Codec information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVhlq.jpg)

According to [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats) this media format is not supported by Android, and upon further [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format) I have learned this format was created by Apple.

In my application I am playing the videos using a standard VideoView and MediaController to give control over playback (very simple and standard, no customization whatsoever). After extensive research on the topic and testing out different solutions to similar issues, I have had no luck. If necessary I will be happy to include code snippets.

The most interesting find through running different tests so far, is playing the videos in my device's media gallery. My app has the ability to download the videos directly to the device. The device I have been testing with is a Samsung Galaxy s9+. I downloaded a few of the videos from my app to my phone's gallery, and when I play them through Samsung's default media player, a message pops up saying "can't play audio. Audio codec not supported". However, I also have Google Photos media gallery on this device, and when I play the videos using their media player they do have sound. The fact that the sound can be played using Google's media gallery makes me believe there is in fact some sort of solution out there.

TL;DR - How to play a video with sound that uses sowt/AIFF-C audio codec on Android?

Any light that can be shed on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: check out https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer

Comment: Instead of trying to play an unsupported format, maybe you could try to convert it to a codec that your device could play ?